# Semantic Zoom doesn't work in Windows 8 app

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows, semantic-zoom

I'm trying to use a SemanticZoom in my Windows 8 application and it seems to not work.

Do I do something wrong here ?
I tried pretty much everything I thought that could work but in vain : removed the rowdefinitions, removed the style, removed the templates but still not working...

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <SemanticZoom Grid.RowSpan="2">            
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
             <GridView x:Name="itemGridView"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                      Padding="116,137,40,46"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
                      SelectionMode="None"
                      IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewItemTemplateZoomIn}"
                      ItemsPanel="{StaticResource GridViewItemsPanelTemplate}"
                      helpers:ItemClickCommand.Command="{Binding ServiceClickCommand}">
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="1,0,10,6">
                                    <Button AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                            Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                       Margin="3,-7,10,10"
                                                       Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}"
                                                       FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                                                       Margin="0,-7,0,10"
                                                       Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"
                                                       Margin="0,0,80,0" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <GridView x:Name="itemZoomOutGridView"
                      ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                      Padding="116,175,40,46"
                      SelectionMode="None"
                      IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewItemTemplateZoomOut}"
                      ItemsPanel="{StaticResource GridViewItemsPanelTemplate}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceCategories}">
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What isn't working about it? Is it not showing up? Does it zoom at all? I.e. does the zoomed in view disappear? Are you testing it with mouse or on a device? Are you using the simulator to test touch controls with it? Gotta give more info about what isn't working instead of just "it's not working".

Comment: @NateDiamond Sorry i didn't specify ^^ The semanticzoom is displayed, it works pretty good in general but when i'm clicking on an item on the ZoomedOut, it just go back to the ZoomedIn view without going to the selected item...

Comment: @NateDiamond I'm using MS VS 2013 simulator to test my app but if i deploy the app on my local windows 8 the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the semanticView in itself is working (you can zoom in and zoom out). But when you zoom back in the GridView items are the same and doesn't change according to the ZoomedOutView GridView item you selected.

But with your XAML I think this is normal behaviour, because when you select a category the binding on your gridview in zoomedInView doesn't change.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
```

My first advice would be to bind the ItemsSource to a list in your ViewModel not use a staticRessource.

Secondly you can change the SemanticView this way:

```
<SemanticZoom Grid.RowSpan="2" ViewChangeStarted="SemanticZoomChanged" >
```

And in your code behind add that:

```
private void SemanticZoomChanged(object sender, SemanticZoomViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // First we check that we are going from ZoomedOut to ZoomedIn
   if (e.IsSourceZoomedInView == false)
   {
      // I call a method in my ViewModel giving the chosen category in parameter
      DefaultViewModel.OnSelectedCategoryChanged(e.SourceItem.Item.ToString());
   }
}
```

Using MVVM I know it's ugly to have code in code-behind but this is not a lot and we are calling a method in the ViewModel to do the logic so it's still following MVVM design pattern.

And last we add a function in the ViewModel that will change the ItemsSource of the ZoomedInView

```
OnSelectedCategoryChanged(string chosenCategory)
{
    // Here change the value of your groupedItemsViewSource list
    GroupedItemsViewSource = ....;
}
```

Now it should work as you want to.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I found a way to do what I needed ! :)